# How to count the emojis and display them in a discord bot reaction?

Tags: python, discord

```
for second in range(60):
    message_id = await message.channel.fetch_message(message.id)
    for reaction in message_id.reactions:
        thumbs_up_count = 0
        thumbs_down_count = 0
        if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
            thumbs_up_count = reaction.emoji.count
        if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
            thumbs_down_count = reaction.emoji.count
        await message.edit(content=("**----POLL----** \n \n**Green Today?** :thumbsup: {} \n \n**Red Today?**   :thumbsdown: {}".format(thumbs_up_count,thumbs_down_count)))
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

this is my code, it makes a poll and people react with thumbs up or thumbs down. then it edits the message constantly as the votes come in. the code is not efficient, but I am not seeing where the logical error is. It is not counting the emojis at all and displays 0.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're always replacing the `thumbs_up_count, thumbs_down_count` values with what `reaction.emoji.count` brings, so what you can try is some like this:

```
for second in range(60):
    message_id = await message.channel.fetch_message(message.id)
    for reaction in message_id.reactions:
        thumbs_up_count = 0
        thumbs_down_count = 0
        if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
            thumbs_up_count += reaction.emoji.count
        if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
            thumbs_down_count += reaction.emoji.count
        await message.edit(content=("**----POLL----** \n \n**Green Today?** :thumbsup: {} \n \n**Red Today?**   :thumbsdown: {}".format(thumbs_up_count,thumbs_down_count)))
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

Note that I replaced `=` by `+=` in both cases

Hope it could help you :)